# Occasionally I'm told I have acquired a chest key. Where are the chests?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

In *Assassin's Creed III* I am told I've acquired a key (such as the `Boston Central Key`). Where do I find the associated chest? Furthermore, where are the rest of the chests in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys you find in the game don't really open one specific chest, they just allow you to open chests in a region without having to pick them.  So since you found the `Boston Central Key`, you may open chests found in Boston Central without having to go through that tedious lock picking game, they'll open up immediately for you.

Finding the chests is a different story.  As far as I know, you cannot buy maps that show you their locations like in previous games.  You have to find them.  I don't have any advice for this (I haven't even found them all neither) but just to wander around every inch of the map trying to reveal everything.  Once you are close to a chest and it is in your line of sight, it's location will be revealed on the map.

Comment: You can buy maps for the chests in each area at the shops.

Comment: Keys are kinda pointless given _how easy_ it is to pick a lock.

Comment: @animuson: Well I'll tell you one thing, I always buy everything at stores, maps first. As far as I can remember, none of those maps revealed chest locations. There were always some chests that I come across that a map didn't reveal. Part of that could just be due to the bugs where things just would not show up on the map.

Comment: @CyberSkull: But extremely mundane and tedious considering there were so many chests and it often took close to a minute of fiddling around with the controls just to open the thing.